# Wagtail_Streamblock: How do I get the number of items in a Streamblock from inside a template?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a widget that I'm making. If the item count is 2, I want to load the image differently then I would if the item count is 3. There has to be either 2 or 3 child_blocks in my Streamblock because I set min_num = 2 and max_num = 3. How do I get the number of blocks inside a Streamblock from inside a template?

For instance, {{self.items.length}}

"items" being my Streamblock

I know that's not correct, just using it as example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

A `StreamField` value behaves like a Python list, and within a template you can use the [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#length) template filter to find its length:

`{{ self.items|length }}`